# I want to delete a row with fadeout effect is not working

Tags: php

I Have a table showing data i want to delete a row when a delete button click
i have a bootstrap class to design the table please help and suggest a way to do it

```
     <code><?php
        while ($query = $qry->fetch_object())  {
                     ?>     
                    <tr><td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo  $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td> <button type="button"    class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 0nClick="deleteReminder(<?php  print($query->id);?>)" >
</td>
</tr>
<script>
        function deleteReminder(remId) {
       if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {

              $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "sumthing.php",
              data: "remId="+remId,
             success: function(result){
              console.log(result);
               }
            });

           $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")

            }
            return false;
        }
        </script>
</code>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The fade, the delete, the ajax?

Comment: the fading is not working i am not getting how to select that particular row

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 0nClick="deleteReminder(<?php  print($query->id);?>)" >
```

You have spelled onClick with a `0`. Change it to:

```
<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onClick="deleteReminder(<?php  print($query->id);?>)" >
```

You also need to place an ID on your table row, that you can then pass to the function so it will delete the correct row. You also can't animate background-color. See below:

```
     <?php
        $i = 0;
        while ($query = $qry->fetch_object())  {
            $i = $i + 1;
                     ?>     
                    <tr id="rowNum<?php echo $i; ?>"><td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo  $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo echo $query->Sumthing; ?></td>
                        <td> <button type="button"    class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onClick="deleteReminder('rowNum<?php echo $i; ?>')" >
</td>
</tr>
<script>
        function deleteReminder(remId) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {  
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "sumthing.php",
                    data: "remId="+remId,
                    success: function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
           remId = "#"+remId;
           $(remId).animate({
               opacity: 0
            }, 1000,function(){});
        }
        </script>
```

[Here's a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va4jpn7n/).

Comment: I have done the change but fadeout effect is not working